# How do I search for a UserControl in XAML using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have `UserControl` **UC0** which I use in the XAML markup of another `UserControl`. When I search for all occurrences of **UC0** using Shift-F12 on **UC0**'s definition, Visual Studio does not show me where it's mentioned in XAML.

So how do I search for it in XAML using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> and search for `<local:UC0` across the project or solution. Replace `local` with whatever prefix your namespace is mapped against.

XAML is just text that is eventually compiled to BAML so at design time there is no real reference to the `UserControl`.

I am afraid that the "Find All References" feature in Visual Studio doesn't play with the XAML compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the prefix might even change since I'm using the UserControl across multiple projects in one solution. But I guess there's no better way. Sigh... In a way, WPF is a step back from WinForms... Thanks again.

Comment: @ispiro: Omit the prefix then and search for just `:UC0 `.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea.

Comment: Don't worry. When an answer is "it can't be done" I tend to wait a couple of days before accepting due to the multiple cases in the past where someone later found a way to do it. I have it bookmarked so I don't forget to accept it later.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the plain text search, there is a small dropdown menu to the right of the search button (with an arrow as icon). There you can choose to "Find all".